# Erro quando outra classe chama método de uma Activity

Tags: java, android

No monitoramento ele manda uma SMS para um equipamento que responde com outra SMS e atualizar a tela e no momento que chama o método para atualizar a tela da o erro. Log do Erro:

```
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661): Process: com.example.acquaconnect, PID: 8661
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.acquaconnect.ReceberSms: java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2441)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:139)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:173)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at com.example.acquaconnect.Monitoramento.AtualizaTela(Monitoramento.java:128)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at com.example.acquaconnect.ReceberSms.AtualizaBD(ReceberSms.java:225)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at com.example.acquaconnect.ReceberSms.onReceive(ReceberSms.java:63)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2434)
    01-14 22:45:30.907: E/AndroidRuntime(8661):     ... 10 more
```

Código Monitoramento:

```java
    public class Monitoramento extends ActionBarActivity{

        private static final String CATEGORIA = "acqua";
        private static final String PREF_NAME = "BD";

        TextView monit1,monit2,monit3,monit4,monit5,monit6,monit7,monit8,monit9,monit10,
        monit11,monit12,monit13,monit14,monit15,monit16,monit17;
        String numero ;
        String M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10,M11,M12,M13,M14,M15,M16,M17;
        String L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10,L11,L12,L13,L14,L15,L16,L17;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.monitoramento);

            Button legenda = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butLegenda);
            Button atualizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butAtualizar);

            monit1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit1);
            monit2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit2);
            monit3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit3);
            monit4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit4);
            monit5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit5);
            monit6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit6);
            monit7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit7);
            monit8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit8);
            monit9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit9);
            monit10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit10);
            monit11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit11);
            monit12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit12);
            monit13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit13);
            monit14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit14);
            monit15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit15);
            monit16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit16);
            monit17 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Monit17);

         // VERIFY SHAREDPREFERENCES
                SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                M1 = sp.getString("monit_1", "Desabilitado");
                M2 = sp.getString("monit_2", "Desabilitado");
                M3 = sp.getString("monit_3", "Desabilitado");
                M4 = sp.getString("monit_4", "Desabilitado");
                M5 = sp.getString("monit_5", "Desabilitado");
                M6 = sp.getString("monit_6", "Desabilitado");
                M7 = sp.getString("monit_7", "Desabilitado");
                M8 = sp.getString("monit_8", "Desabilitado");
                M9 = sp.getString("monit_9", "Desabilitado");
                M10 = sp.getString("monit_10", "Desabilitado");
                M11 = sp.getString("monit_11", "Desabilitado");
                M12 = sp.getString("monit_12", "Desabilitado");
                M13 = sp.getString("monit_13", "Desabilitado");
                M14 = sp.getString("monit_14", "Desabilitado");
                M15 = sp.getString("monit_15", "Desabilitado");
                M16 = sp.getString("monit_16", "Desabilitado");
                M17 = sp.getString("monit_17", "Desabilitado");
                String numcel = sp.getString("num_cel", "");

                L1 = sp.getString("leg_1", "Desabilitado");
                L2 = sp.getString("leg_2", "Desabilitado");
                L3 = sp.getString("leg_3", "Desabilitado");
                L4 = sp.getString("leg_4", "Desabilitado");
                L5 = sp.getString("leg_5", "Desabilitado");
                L6 = sp.getString("leg_6", "Desabilitado");
                L7 = sp.getString("leg_7", "Desabilitado");
                L8 = sp.getString("leg_8", "Desabilitado");
                L9 = sp.getString("leg_9", "Desabilitado");
                L10 = sp.getString("leg_10", "Desabilitado");
                L11 = sp.getString("leg_11", "Desabilitado");
                L12 = sp.getString("leg_12", "Desabilitado");
                L13 = sp.getString("leg_13", "Desabilitado");
                L14 = sp.getString("leg_14", "Desabilitado");
                L15 = sp.getString("leg_15", "Desabilitado");
                L16 = sp.getString("leg_16", "Desabilitado");
                L17 = sp.getString("leg_17", "Desabilitado");

                //Exibe o valor na tela
                monit1.setText(M1);
                monit2.setText(M2);
                monit3.setText(M3);
                monit4.setText(M4);
                monit5.setText(M5);
                monit6.setText(M6);
                monit7.setText(M7);
                monit8.setText(M8);
                monit9.setText(M9);
                monit10.setText(M10);
                monit11.setText(M11);
                monit12.setText(M12);
                monit13.setText(M13);
                monit14.setText(M14);
                monit15.setText(M15);
                monit16.setText(M16);
                monit17.setText(M17);
                numero = numcel;

        }

    //------------BOTAO-ATUALIZAR-------------- 
        public void butAtualizar(View v){
            String mensagem = "*st1";

            Sms sms = new Sms();
            sms.enviarSms(Monitoramento.this, numero,mensagem);

        }

        public void butLegenda(View v){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Legenda.class));
        }

        public void AtualizaTela(){
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            M1 = sp.getString("monit_1", "Desabilitado");
            M2 = sp.getString("monit_2", "Desabilitado");
            M3 = sp.getString("monit_3", "Desabilitado");
            M4 = sp.getString("monit_4", "Desabilitado");
            M5 = sp.getString("monit_5", "Desabilitado");
            M6 = sp.getString("monit_6", "Desabilitado");
            M7 = sp.getString("monit_7", "Desabilitado");
            M8 = sp.getString("monit_8", "Desabilitado");
            M9 = sp.getString("monit_9", "Desabilitado");
            M10 = sp.getString("monit_10", "Desabilitado");
            M11 = sp.getString("monit_11", "Desabilitado");
            M12 = sp.getString("monit_12", "Desabilitado");
            M13 = sp.getString("monit_13", "Desabilitado");
            M14 = sp.getString("monit_14", "Desabilitado");
            M15 = sp.getString("monit_15", "Desabilitado");
            M16 = sp.getString("monit_16", "Desabilitado");
            M17 = sp.getString("monit_17", "Desabilitado");

            //Exibe o valor na tela
            monit1.setText(M1);
            monit2.setText(M2);
            monit3.setText(M3);
            monit4.setText(M4);
            monit5.setText(M5);
            monit6.setText(M6);
            monit7.setText(M7);
            monit8.setText(M8);
            monit9.setText(M9);
            monit10.setText(M10);
            monit11.setText(M11);
            monit12.setText(M12);
            monit13.setText(M13);
            monit14.setText(M14);
            monit15.setText(M15);
            monit16.setText(M16);
            monit17.setText(M17);

        }
        //-----------BOTÃO DE VOLTAR--------------------    
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Usuario.class));
        }
    //-----------FIM BOTÃO DE VOLTAR--------------------


    }//fim
```

Linha do Erro :
Em `AtualizaTela()`

```
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Código ReceberSms:

```java
    public class ReceberSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String CATEGORIA = "acqua";
        private static final String PREF_NAME = "BD";

        String L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10,L11,L12,L13,L14,L15,L16,L17;
        String M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10,M11,M12,M13,M14,M15,M16,M17;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Sms sms = new Sms();
            //Lê a mensagem
            SmsMessage msg = sms.receberMensagem(intent);
            String celular = msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            String mensagem = msg.getDisplayMessageBody();

            // VERIFY SHAREDPREFERENCES
            SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String numcel = sp.getString("num_cel", "");


            if(celular.equals(numcel)){
                if(mensagem.contains("MONIT-110")){

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putString("mensagem_cel_monit", mensagem);
                    editor.putString("alarme_on", "yes");
                    editor.commit();

                    //chama outra activity
                    intent = new Intent(context, CriaNotificacao.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }else if(mensagem.contains("STATUS-110")){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

                    editor.putString("mensagem_cel_status", mensagem);
                    editor.commit();

                    AtualizaBD(context);

                }
            } 
        }//fim receive


        public void AtualizaBD(Context context){
            // VERIFY SHAREDPREFERENCES
            SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            L1 = sp.getString("leg_1", "Desabilitado");
            L2 = sp.getString("leg_2", "Desabilitado");
            L3 = sp.getString("leg_3", "Desabilitado");
            L4 = sp.getString("leg_4", "Desabilitado");
            L5 = sp.getString("leg_5", "Desabilitado");
            L6 = sp.getString("leg_6", "Desabilitado");
            L7 = sp.getString("leg_7", "Desabilitado");
            L8 = sp.getString("leg_8", "Desabilitado");
            L9 = sp.getString("leg_9", "Desabilitado");
            L10 = sp.getString("leg_10", "Desabilitado");
            L11 = sp.getString("leg_11", "Desabilitado");
            L12 = sp.getString("leg_12", "Desabilitado");
            L13 = sp.getString("leg_13", "Desabilitado");
            L14 = sp.getString("leg_14", "Desabilitado");
            L15 = sp.getString("leg_15", "Desabilitado");
            L16 = sp.getString("leg_16", "Desabilitado");
            L17 = sp.getString("leg_17", "Desabilitado");

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            String mensagemStatus = sp.getString("mensagem_cel_status", "");

            if(L1.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_1", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E01-DES")){editor.putString("monit_1", "Não");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E01-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_1", "Sim");editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L2.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_2", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E02-DES")){editor.putString("monit_2", "Não");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E02-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_2", "Sim");editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L3.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_3", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E03-DES")){editor.putString("monit_3", "Não");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E03-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_3", "Sim");editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L4.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_4", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E04-DES")){editor.putString("monit_4", "Não");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E04-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_4", "Sim");editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L5.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_5", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E05-DES")){editor.putString("monit_5", "Não");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E05-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_5", "Sim");editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L6.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_6", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E06-DES")){editor.putString("monit_6", "Não");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E06-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_6", "Sim");editor.commit();}
            }


            if(L7.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_7", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{  
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E07-DES")){editor.putString("monit_7", "Desligado");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E07-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_7", "Ligado");editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L8.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_8", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E08-DES")){editor.putString("monit_8", "Desligado");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E08-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_8", "Ligado");editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L9.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_9", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E09-DES")){editor.putString("monit_9", "Desligado");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E09-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_9", "Ligado");editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L10.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_10", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E10-DES")){editor.putString("monit_10", "Desligado");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E10-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_10", "Ligado");editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L11.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_11", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("E11-DES")){editor.putString("monit_11", "Desligado");editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("E11-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_11", "Ligado");editor.commit();}
            }


            if(L12.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_12", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("S01-DES")){editor.putString("monit_12", "Manual"); editor.putBoolean("but_1", false);editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("S01-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_12", "Automático"); editor.putBoolean("but_1", true);editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L13.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_13", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("S02-DES")){editor.putString("monit_13", "Manual"); editor.putBoolean("but_2", false);editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("S02-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_13", "Automático"); editor.putBoolean("but_2", true);editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L14.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_14", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("S03-DES")){editor.putString("monit_14", "Manual"); editor.putBoolean("but_3", false);editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("S03-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_14", "Automático"); editor.putBoolean("but_3", true);editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L15.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_15", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("S04-DES")){editor.putString("monit_15", "Manual");editor.putBoolean("but_4", false);editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("S04-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_15", "Automático"); editor.putBoolean("but_4", true);editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L16.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_16", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("S05-DES")){editor.putString("monit_16", "Manual"); editor.putBoolean("but_5", false);editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("S05-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_16", "Automático"); editor.putBoolean("but_6", true);editor.commit();}
            }

            if(L17.equals("Desabilitado")){
                editor.putString("monit_17", "Desabilitado");editor.commit();
            }else{
                if(mensagemStatus.contains("S06-DES")){editor.putString("monit_17", "Manual"); editor.putBoolean("but_6", false);editor.commit();
                }else if(mensagemStatus.contains("S06-ATI")){editor.putString("monit_17", "Automático"); editor.putBoolean("but_6", true);editor.commit();}
            }
            Monitoramento moni = new Monitoramento();
            moni.AtualizaTela();

        }//fim aatualiza

    }//fim
```

Linhas dos erros:
Em `AtualizaBD()`

```
        moni.AtualizarTela();
```

Em `onRceive()`

```
        AtualizaBD(context);
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5991458/4443230 -- Parece que o getSharedPreferences só pode ser chamado depois do OnCreate da Activity.

Comment: é que estava funcionando certinho, mas quando troquei no receberSms para chamar um metodo de outra classe que deu o erro

Comment: Associe um: try { //seu código   }  catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

Comment: Para entendermos o erro.

Comment: Identifica a linha 128 de `Monitoramento.java`, 225 de `ReceberSms.java` e 63 de `ReceberSms.java`.

Comment: editei e coloquei as linhas do erro @JorgeB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe `Monitoramento` é uma `Activity`, não pode ser instanciada da forma normal, usando `new`, mas sim através de `context.startActivity` para que todo o processo de criação seja efetuado.

É por isso que `context.getSharedPreferences` retorna ***null***.

Uma forma de implementar o que você pretende seria definir um `BroadcastReceiver` dentro da Activity `Monitoramento` cuja função seria actualizar a tela.
Como o `BroadcastReceiver` é interno pode chamar diretamente o método `AtualizaTela()`.

Defina uma classe derivada de *BroadcastReceiver* na sua *Activity* :

```
public class ActualizaTelaReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
       {    
           String action = intent.getAction();
           if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("ACTUALIZA_TELA")){
               //Chame o seu método    
               Monitoramento.ActualizaTela();
           }
       }
}
```

Crie uma instância de `ActualizaTelaReceiver` no método `onCreate`:

```
private ActualizaTelaReceiver actualizaTelaReceiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    ....
    actualizaTelaReceiver = new ActualizaTelaReceiver();
}
```

Registe o *BroadcastReceiver* no método *onResume* da *Activity*:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(actualizaTelaReceiver, new IntentFilter("ACTUALIZA_TELA"));
}
```

Faça o *"Unregister"* no método *onPause*

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    unregisterReceiver(actualizaTelaReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Em `ReceberSms`, em vez de instanciar `Monitoramento` e chamar `AtualizaTela()`, seria lançado esse `BroadcastReceiver`, via `sendBroadcast()`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("ACTUALIZA_TELA");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: ´01-15 15:07:55.901: E/AndroidRuntime(29167): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.acquaconnect/com.example.acquaconnect.Monitoramento}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: null´  

fiz como você disse mas dá esse erro, na linha em que uso o 
`unregisterReceiver(atualizaTelaReceiver);`

Comment: Você colocou `registerReceiver(actualizaTelaReceiver, new IntentFilter("ACTUALIZA_TELA"));` no método `onResume`?

Comment: sim fiz exatamente como você explicou aqui

Comment: Falta instanciar ActualizaTelaReceiver e atribui-la a ao atributo actualizaTelaReceiver. Faça `actualizaTelaReceiver = new ActualizaTelaReceiver();` no método `onCreate`

Comment: Era realmente o que faltava, muito obrigada pela ajuda, estava sem saber como resolver isso. Mais uma vez obrigada.