# Notificar a Activity atual que função em background terminou de ser executada Android

Tags: android, asynctask, funções

Tenho uma classe que busca uma lista de clientes em background com uma `AsyncTask`. Ela pode ser chamada de qualquer `Activity`, e não retorna nada, apenas busca a lista de clientes que vem em `json` e salva essa lista como `string` em um `SharedPreferences`. 
 Inicialmente, estou mandando buscar a lista em minha tela de login, assim, quando trazer os dados do usuario do banco de dados, ele já manda buscar a lista de clientes(para reduzir a espera de busca dos dados), mas eu precisava que quando essa classe salvasse a lista no `SharedPreferences` a minha `Activity` que é aberta depois do login fosse notificada para então eu preencher um `RecyclerView` com ela. Pensei em Implementar uma `Interface` na `AsyncTask` mas ela retorna para a `Activity` que a chamou. 
Tem algum método que notifique a `Activity` mesmo que a função não tenha sido iniciada por ela?

Obs: Caso não tenha entendido a pergunta, comente antes de negativar que terei prazer em esclarecer suas dúvidas.

Comment: Sim é possível, mas essa abordagem pode falhar caso a lista seja salva antes da activação da *activty*. Nesse caso a *activity* não recebe a notificação.

Comment: Tem algum outro jeito?

Comment: O normal é os dados serem lidos pela a *activity* que os usa ou então serem passados a ela.

Comment: Já fiz isso mas as vezes demora muito e preciso que a busca seja rapida.

Comment: Se quiser tentar, mesmo sabendo que pode falhar, veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46976/2541).

Comment: vou dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Tem como fazer o que você deseja de diversas formas, para uma solução mais simples eu utilizo um `BroadCastReceiver` porém se você for usar em várias classes, talvez seja melhor criar uma interface para isto.

Segue um exemplo do Braodcast:

Na **Activity**

```
BroadCastReceiver myReceiver;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction("lista.atualizada");

            myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {  //  < ------ Declare o Bradcast como global

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   // Atualize o que quiser, foi atualizado

                }
            };
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

}


 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver); // <---- não esqueça de destruir o receiver junto com a activity
    }
```

Então na sua **task**:

```
Intent atualizouLista = new Intent();

atualizouLista.setAction("lista.atualizada"); // < ---- aqui é o nome da sua "ação" a mesma que você registrou no receiver
mContext.sendBroadcast(atualizouLista); // < --- repare que estou passando mContext, na sua Task você precisa manter uma referência do seu contexto.
```

Comment: tem algum problema se a activity ainda não tiver sido aberta?

Comment: O receiver é registrado no método onCreate, então ele é vinculado ao Activity Life Cicle (onCreate,onStart,onResume,etc..) , se você for iniciar um serviço em uma activity e receber o resultado em outra, precisará implementar um "Bus", que seria uma Thread que ficaria rodando sem ficar vinculada ao lifecicle. É meio chato fazer isso na unha, então recomendo usar alguma LIb, eu costumo usar a Robospice (que inclusive integro com Retrofit,Gson e OrmLite facilmente), mas se não me engano o Otto faz algo semelhante

Comment: @BrunoRomualdo Qualquer que seja o sistema de notificação utilizado(incluindo um "EventBus"), se a notificação for lançada antes de se ter registado para a receber, ela não será recebida.

Comment: @ramaral Sim, você perderá a notificação, a não ser que se utilize algum cache, o Robospice mantem a notificação no cache, então ao registrar o listener você pode recuperá-la.

Comment: Olhe esse infográfico para entender melhor, você pode executar o serviço e recebe-lo em uma Activity que não foi iniciada ainda. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/master/gfx/RoboSpice-InfoGraphics.png

Comment: Estava agora mesmo a olhar para isso, se reparar bem ele notifica uma nova(da mesma/recreada) activity e não uma activity diferente.

Comment: @ramaral negativo, verifique que no próprio infográfico mostra a notificação no "back", eu mesmo uso ele da seguinte forma : inicio o serviço de busca, o usuário continua mexendo e minhas activitys possuem um listener pro serviço, então, independente de qual activity estou a notificação chega, o serviço roda em paralelo e a Activity pega do cache ou da requisição (dependendo de alguns parâmetros)

Comment: Acredito que tenha razão, não posso teimar pois nunca utilizei o Robospice.

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma olhada.